# Passing a collection of arrays to function argument

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

How do I create and pass a collection of arrays to a function, have the function perform an operation on each array in the collection and return the arrays (likely in collection form) back to the routine? The arrays need to maintain their identity (pass to and from the operation function by reference). This will help me to clean up and condense my current code. I'm not a professional programmer, so I realize that my code could be drastically improved. Any guidance is appreciated.

An example of current code:

```
import numpy as np

# Function that performs some operation on array (matrix)
def addLine(x):
    x = np.vstack([x,np.random.rand(1,5)])
    return x

def mainLoop():
    A = np.zeros((1,5),dtype=np.float32)
    B = np.ones((1,5),dtype=np.float32)
    C = np.ones((1,5),dtype=np.float32)

    # Do stuff

    A = addLine(A)
    B = addLine(B)
    C = addLine(C)
```

What I would like to do:

```
# Function that accepts a collection of arrays as argument, performs 
# operation, and returns modified arrays to the same identity / name     
def addLines(x):
    for n in range(len(x)):
        x[n] = addLine(x)
        return x[n]

def mainLoop():
    A = np.zeros((1,5),dtype=np.float32)
    B = np.ones((1,5),dtype=np.float32)
    C = np.ones((1,5),dtype=np.float32)

    # Do stuff
    # Create a collection of all arrays to perform operations on
    AllArrays = [A,B,C]

    # Pass collection of arrays to function (I likely need a for loop here)
    AllArrays = addLines(AllArrays)

    # Perform further operations on individual arrays
    A = A+2
    B = B+1
    C = C-1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this slight change?

```
def addLine(*args):
    args = map(lambda x: np.vstack([x,np.random.rand(1,5)]), *args)
    return args

AllArrays = addLine(AllArrays)

A, B, C = AllArrays

A

array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.66237197,  0.07125813,  0.5454597 ,  0.44901189,  0.89820099]])
```

Comment: Thanks @aws_apprentice, I'll try this.